# Windows 10, Windows Key + Right (or Left) arrow key, can I turn off the other window selection

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-key

I recently moved from Windows 7 to Windows 10, and when I press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>, the other side of the screen shows all of my other windows. This is very annoying to me !

Can I get Windows 10 to stop doing this and act more like it did in Windows 7?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

go to System > Settings > Multitasking and turn "When I snap a window, show what can snap next to it" off

source: [post in Microsoft community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-desktop/windows-key-arrow-key-functionality/74a38d68-895d-48b2-84df-aef4fe3a7bd7)